# How to write each array element to a different file

Tags: ruby

My code:

```
allfiles = [123, 234, 345]
allurls = ["http://www.123.com", "http://www.234.com"]

for allfile in allfiles
    name = allfile + ".html"
    File.open(name, "w") do |file|
         for allurl in allurls 
           file.write(RestClient.get(allurl))
         end 
    end
end
```

> Error: String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Basically, I want to download HTML of corresponding URLs, and save it to corresponding files named after their URLs. Whats wrong with my code??

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `name = allfile + ".html"` to `name = (allfile).to_s + ".html"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

The error is due to this line `name = allfile + ".html"`. You cannot add a ***string*** to a ***number***. Changing it like below will solve your problem

```
allfiles = [123, 234, 345]
allurls = ["http://www.123.com", "http://www.234.com"]

for allfile in allfiles
    name = (allfile).to_s + ".html"
    File.open(name, "w") do |file|
         for allurl in allurls 
           file.write(RestClient.get(allurl))
         end 
    end
end
```

You can use [***string interpolation***](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) too.

```
allfiles = [123, 234, 345]
allurls = ["http://www.123.com", "http://www.234.com"]

for allfile in allfiles
    name = "#{allfile}" + ".html"
    File.open(name, "w") do |file|
         for allurl in allurls 
           file.write(RestClient.get(allurl))
         end 
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan! Actually, I was using the string interpolation method before creating the allfiles array. However, since my actual filename contains /, which is confused with directories. I tried using '#{allfile}', but it doesnt work. Any ideas?? (single quote is meant to ignore the / )

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming in the line

> name = allfile + ".html"

Hera allfile is an integer and you are trying to add it to a string. You needd to convert 'allfile' to a string using the **to_s** method.

```
allfiles = [123, 234, 345]
allurls = ["http://www.123.com", "http://www.234.com"]

for allfile in allfiles
    name = allfile.to_s + ".html"
    File.open(name, "w") do |file|
         for allurl in allurls 
           file.write(RestClient.get(allurl))
         end 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, file name prefixes need to be strings so either change `allfiles` to `['123', '234', '345']` or convert later with `String#to_s` in expression:

`name = allfile.to_s + ".html"`

Second, iterating over collection using `for` is unidiomatic in Ruby. Rather use `Enumerable` methods and block style:

```
allfiles.each do |allfile|
  File.open("#{allfile}.html") do |file|
    allurls.each {|allurl| file.write RestClient.get(allurl)}
  end
end
```

Update by the OP's comment:

```
domains = ['123', '234', '345']
domains.each do |domain|
  File.open("#{domain}.html") do |file|
    file.write RestClient.get("http://www.#{domain}.com/")
  end
end
```

Only works for urls in www.<domain>.com format. It'd require modification to be more generic.

Comment: Thanks, now files are saving, but both 123.com and 234.com are saved to 123.html and 234.html. Is there a way to solve this problem??

Comment: Above behavior is equivalent to the example from original question. How would you like url responses should be saved ? I can update the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for replying! I want 123.com to be saved to 123.html, and 234.com to be saved to 234.html. 

I have actually tried using the string interpolation method mentioned by pavan. But since the actual file name contains /, and that using '#{allfile} doesnt work, i resolved to creating a new allfiles array, which made everything more complicated. It might be easier if you know how to ignore  / in file names. ( / is confused with directories) Thanks!